# How do I store the char of a byte in a binary file at a specific index in C++

Tags: c++

I am doing a school project where I need to store the byte at a certain index, edit it, and then execute a program, after I am done executing the program , I will have to restore the byte to ensure that the executable does not break.

Here is part of the code that I have tried

```
unsigned int x; // To convert the hex string into int
stringstream ss;
ss<<hex<<offset;//Offset is the hex string 
ss>>x;
file.seekg(x);//To move pointer ( i believe) to the specified offset of the binary file
char bytevalue[1];
file.read(bytevalue,1);
cout << "Final byte value : " << bytevalue[0]<<endl;
```

The problem I am facing now is that when it is printing bytevalue[0]
it will always be this special character "á" (i cant find the exact letter but it is the same letter but the line goes downwards instead of up).

anyone knows where I could be wrong?

Comment: _i cant find the exact letter_ You meant `à`?

Comment: I didn't get your exact issue. Is your problem that you want to print the byte value as number instead of a letter? In this case, the formatted output operator of `char` is a wrong choice but you can fix this by a type cast: `(unsigned)(unsigned char)bytevalue[0]`. This will convert the `char` to `unsigned` and use the formatted output operator for the latter (which will result in the integral value printed).

Comment: yes, it is the letter à
I want to get the original char which is definitely not à as I have seen the actual value of it in a hex editor, so I do not know where I have went wrong

Comment: When you open `file`, do you specifically ask for `binary` mode?

Comment: yep I opened it in binarymode

Comment: _I want to get the original char which is definitely not à as I have seen the actual value of it in a hex editor_ Then, it would help to mention what value you saw in the hex editor. Furthermore, when you output a character to console the output in console may be matter of encoding. If you write a `char` into a file the resp. byte should be written without any encoding issues. (Of course, the encoding issues may arise again as soon as you display the file in a text viewer but not in a hex viewer.)